# How to declare read only immutable reference?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some information, which is not changed during execution program. It is sort of static information. I am using following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static readonly List<int> = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
};
```

Unfortunately during execution of program, I can change fields of such `static` member. As result I have the following warning:

> "Do not declare read only mutable reference types".

What is best practise to cope with this problem?

Comment: Is `TypeFace` your own class? If so, can you make it either immutable or "optionally immutable" (like `CultureInfo`)? In general, I'd suggest exposing properties rather than fields, btw... and following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, It is system class. How can I make it immutable?

Comment: At first glance, that looks immutable already. Which properties are you able to change?

Comment: Declaring a field `readonly` does not affect the members of the class. It just means you cannot re-assign the field. You must make each member of the class read-only to get the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, declaring field as readonly prevents you to replacing instance of this object. But in the case of reference type, you can change state of object

Comment: May I ask how can you change TypeFace fields? I'm seeing only "get" (readonly) properties. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.typeface(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Alexey Groshev, good catch. I made mistake, but it is not principal. As for example, I can use class which have also setters

Comment: The problem is the compiler warning, right? If the type is effectively immutable (say, it has no public setters) I think it would be OK to suppress this warning; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx

Comment: @Steve Cooper, not only. I want to control acces to such object and prevent on changes

Comment: Alex; that particular class (Typeface) doesn't seem to have any public setters, so this class cannot have changes made. More generally, I don't know how to solve this problem but for this class only, you might be OK to simply ignore the warning.

Comment: Right - so the "Do not declare read-only mutable reference types" doesn't apply, as `TypeFace` isn't mutable. It's not clear whether your question is *actually* about this situation, or about one involving a genuinely-mutable type.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I meant about common situation. I just did't know that TypeFace class is immutable (see p.s. section of question)

Comment: Right - I think you'd be better off editing the question to give an example where it's an actual problem, e.g. exposing a `List<T>` or a `CultureInfo`. It really depends on the type though - some have other types acting as read-only "views" over the mutable type, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, it's not possible to make the members of someone else's class immutable. I'm guessing your familiar with the C++ concept of a const reference, but C# does not have anything like that.

If you want to control access, I'd make the typeface private, and add read-only static properties and methods to Foo. This means you could get read-only access like;

```
Foo.TypeFaceSize;
Foo.TypeFaceName;
```

Comment: As I understood, the only way to use code contracts to check possible changes of this field?

Comment: I've not tried that -- I would be interested to know if you succeed. It seems to me that TypeFace is in reality immutable but the compiler doesn't know that -- I'd consider supressing the warning in code - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The C# compiler can only enforce readonly access to a property or a field. If you make a field readonly, the settable properties of the object in this field are still settable and the only way to change that is to modify the class definition of the object.

You could possibly wrap the object in your own custom class and allow only getters. But you may need to have several layers of wrappers, so I would suggest not doing it and just paying attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn a mutable type into an immutable type in C# *as is*.

If you want to expose `TypeFace` **like** an immutable type you could *wrap* it with a type that has the same properties but it exposes them as read-only properties:

```
public class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class AReadOnly
{
     public AReadOnly(A a)
     {
         A = a;
     }

     private A A { get; }

     public string Text => A.Text;
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        A = new AReadOnly(_A);
    }

    private A _A { get; } = new A();
    public AReadOnly A { get; }
}
```